# How to get one random HTML file from one folder and add it to an iframe?

Tags: jquery

I have a folder called `myfolder` with several files. I would like to select only the HTML files of this folder, and put them randomly into an iframe.

So this is my idea:

```js
// Get HTML files

var pages = ["myfolder/1.html", "myfolder/2.html", "myfolder/3.html"]; // Instead of this, all HTML files of the folder 'myfolder/' should be selected


// Get one random HTML file of selection and add it to the iframe

$(".random-page").attr("src", "myfolder/" + pages[Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length)]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe class="random-page"></iframe>
```

What can be written instead of `var pages = ["myfolder/1.html", "myfolder/2.html", "myfolder/3.html"];` to select all HTML files from one folder? And does it work then with the code that I wrote?

Comment: Are you trying to automatically populate the list of possible HTML files without having to hard-code them in an array? The only way to do that is via server-side code (e.g. PHP) which can read the directory contents and generate the list to be used in Javascript. On the other hand, if you know that there will always be, say, 3 HTML files, and they will always be named `n.html` (where n=1...3), then you can shorten your code. Which of these two options do you prefer?

Comment: @kmoser Thanks for your answer! I didn't know it's not possible with JavaScript to count the amount of the existing files. But I think I will know the amount. Let's say it are always 10. How can the code be shortened then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know there will be exactly 10 files, named `1.html`, `2.html`, etc., there is no need for your `pages` array:

```
$(".random-page").attr('src', 'myfolder/' + ( Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ) + '.html');
```